# Create new documents and insert record in couchbase database

Tags: couchbase

I'm new to couchbase database. I want to create a new document using couchbase Query Workbench Developer Preview. I have seen lots of links for select statement but I didn't see for creating tables. Is there any ddl kind of things to create a document.Your assistance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no tables in Couchbase. You have buckets, which at the moment serve both as namespace and resource allocation unit (credentials, memory quota etc).

To create buckets you have to use either Admin Console, or [bucket management REST API](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/rest-api/rest-bucket-intro.html).

Also keep in mind that Couchbase is [schemaless database](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/data-modeling/concepts-data-modeling-intro.html#story-h2-2), so the structure of the document is not bound to the bucket. To mutate the data, you can look at [INSERT](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/insert.html), [UPDATE](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/update.html) and [UPSERT](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/upsert.html) statements in the N1QL reference manual.

Comment: As well as DELETE and MERGE.